# Why is .Net Core 2 not incorporated into my Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, .net-core, visual-studio-2017

After installing the .Net Core [SDK](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core#windowscmd) 2, I'm still missing core version 2 as shown in the screenshot below.

**Note:** I am using Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2017, Version 15.2 (26430.16) and Microsoft .Net Framework version 4.6.01038

What should I do?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just update to Visual Studio 15.3: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/releasenotes/vs2017-relnotes

Answer (score 1):

You should do an Update to Version 15.3